# C++ program for calculating averages

Tags: c++

I'm taking intro to C++ online and it's moving way too fast for me. I grasp the general concepts, but that's mostly it. I've written about 5 programs so far and I'm having problems laying this out logically and there are 2 functions that are required for use that I haven't seen before. Any help and direction would be awesome. This is the question from the book:

> Write a program that calculates the average of a group of test scores,
>   where the lowest score in the group is dropped. It should use the
>   following functions:
>
> 1. `void getScore()`: should ask user for test score, sore it in a regerence parameter variable, and validate it. This function should be
>      called by *main* once for each of the five scores to be entered.
> 2. `void calcAverage()`: should calculate and display the average of the four highest scores. This function should he called just once by
>      `main`, and should be passed the five test scores.
> 3. `int findLowest()`: should find and return the lowest of the five scores passed to it. It should be called `calcAverage`, which uses the
>      function to determine which of the five scores to drop.
>
> Input Validation: Do not accept test scores lower than 0 or greater than 100.

Here is what I have so far and I know it looks bad, but the more I mess with it the more damage I do. There is an error when I use the calcAverage header and one other after the void getScore prototype, but I don't know why and I definitely don't know how to fix them. After I have used cin.get to get the test scores I don't understand exactly where those go either or how to call them out of their hiding place. I totally missed that concept in the book. I know using the && operator I can make a statement setting the limits using 
(0 >= && <= 100) but I don't know where to put that either. Like I said, any help and definitely any explanations of why would help tremendously. The book I'm using is starting out with C++ 7th edition by Tony Gaddis if that helps any.

```
//This program calculates the average of a group of test scores
//and removes the lowest score.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getScore(int &, int &, int &, int &, int &)
void calcAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4)
void findLowest(num)

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int num4;
    int num5;
    int score1;
    int score2;
    int score3;
    int score4;

    int findLowest();       
    calcAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4);
    getScore(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);

    cout << "Enter 5 Test Scores" << endl;
    cin.get ();

    void getScore(int &calcAverage, int &num1, int &num2, int &num3, int &num4, int &num5)
    {
        void findLowest(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5)

        void calcAverage((score1 &+ score2  + score3 + score4)/4);
        {
            calcAverage = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4)/4;
        }
    }

    cout << "The average is " << calcAverage << endl;
    cout << calcAverage << "." << endl;

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: I would start with reformatting your code. `\`enter code here\`` things aren't meant to be there. I suggest you go back to the book, and rewrite the whole thing from scratch, using proper formatting and not guessworking this time.

Comment: I recommend getting your book out and re-reading the chapters that the class has gone over so far. Anything we help you with here isn't really going to help you understand the subject, which is the real problem

Comment: function definition inside another function is interesting but not supported in C++

Comment: @piotruś, gcc supports sub-function declarations. Also from what I've read C++ is going to support it in the standard... That being said, at this point you should not even try to use it.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the reformatting. Just to clarify, I'm not being lazy or anything. This semester started Jan 6th and I got the pleasure of late registering because of a lazy woman at my school not doing her job. This in turn caused my book ordering process to go behind and I didn't receive my book until Jan 28th. At that point, I had already turned in 2 quizzes and written 2 programs. This is a compacted course and since Jan 6th we are on page 365. I've read literally every word in the book to the place we are now and taken notes, but int findLowest() hasn't been seen or demonstrated yet.

Comment: @daplumpkin Blah, blah, TL;DR; _There is an error when I use the calcAverage header and one other after the void getScore prototype, but I don't know why and I definitely don't know how to fix them._ That's too vague, clarify and get a point. This is not your homework rescue service!!

Comment: @ potrius, The last chapter did cover local and global variables with the same name and also functions within functions. Now that you mention that I don't think I need to be doing functions within functions for this anyways

Comment: @AlexisWilke declaration, not definition

Comment: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

Comment: @name i don't know, I don't want the answer. I don't know where I'm doing good or bad with this. Being in a computer programming course for a month with no programming experience isn't easy when it's moving this fast

Comment: @potrius, I changed that to a prototype instead of definition. I have no clue why I had that in there like the header

Comment: @piotruś, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

Comment: @AlexisWilke Nested functions are supported as an extension in GNU C, but are not supported by GNU C++, only declarations are.

Comment: @piotrus we did go over nested functions, but I think I was trying to next, define, and use them globally. I restarted, defining the functions first and so far I haven't had the urge to nest anymore functions. Putting main last hadn't occurred to me for some reason, but now it's making way more sense.

Answer (score 1):

As I have understood from the description words **segerence parameter variable** denote an array. So instead of definitions (why is there only four variables?)

```
int score1;
int score2;
int score3;
int score4;
```

you should declare an array. For example

```
const int N = 5;
int scores[N];
```

Also as it follows from the assignment function getScore should be declared as

```
void getScore( int scores[], int i );
```

that is for each element of the array you should call this function passing to it the array and the index of a next element of the array.

Correspondingly functions calcAverage and findLowest should be decalred the following way

```
void calcAverage( int scores[], int n );
int findLowest( int scores[], int n );
```

where the second parameters specifies the number of elements in the array.

Take into account that you may not define one function inside another function. All functions shall be declared before their usage.

Function main could be defined the following way

```
int main()
{
   const int N = 5;
   int scores[N];

   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) getScore( scores, i );

   calcAverage( scores, N );

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I am sorry. I read word **regerence** as **sequence** I think you meant **reference**

In this case you indeed should declare five separate variables.

So the function declarations will look as

```
void getScore( int &score );
void calcAverage( int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5 );
int findLowest( int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5 );
```

and main will look as

```
int main()
{
   int score1;
   int score2;
   int score3;
   int score4;
   int score5;

   getScore( score1 );
   getScore( score2 );
   getScore( score3 );
   getScore( score4 );
   getScore( score5 );

   calcAverage( score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 );

   return 0;
}
```

I will show the definition of function findLowest

```
int findLowest( int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5 )
{
   int lowest = score1;

   if ( score2 < lowest ) lowest = score2;
   if ( score3 < lowest ) lowest = score3;
   if ( score4 < lowest ) lowest = score4;
   if ( score5 < lowest ) lowest = score5;

   return lowest;
}
```

Of course it would be simpler to write

```
int findLowest( int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4, int score5 )
{
   return std::min( { score1, score2, score3, score4, score5 } );
}
```

if you would know standard algorithms. :)

Comment: unfortunately arrays are the next chapter and we can't use them yet.

Comment: so after I've properly defined all of the functions I use, then i make my main function and just call them all?

Comment: @daplumpkin I showed how main should be defined. All you need is to define other functions yourself.

Comment: thanks vlad, i didn't know i was doing that backwards

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about what the program is asking you to do and then build it incrementally, rather than all at once.

Start with this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

}
```

and then add small chunks at a time. Think about what each function is for.

For instance start with your getScore() function. You are currently trying to put the code for asking for the scores in the program rather than in your getScore function. The instructions say that you write the function and then each time you need to get a number you use the function.

You should put all function declarations above the main function. You have the scores as parameters, but remember that a parameter is what you put in a function. It should look more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getScore(){
    int v;                           //Create temporary variable v
    cout << "Enter a score: " << ;   //ask user for score
    cin >> v ;                       // user enters score and it is stored in v
    cout << endl;                    //new line for pretty formatting
    return v;                        //function returns v
}

int main() {

    int num1 = getScore();           //Everytime you use the function it will ask for a number.
    int num2 = getScore();

}
```

This example will store the first two numbers. you can then add code to print the numbers using cout. Then compile, fix any errors, and now you know that part of your code works. Then move on to another function. This approach makes programs much less daunting.

Comment: We just started using functions other that main so I missed that all the other declarations go above it. Is that required or make it neater and easier to read? int num1 = getScore();   when num1 - num5 are entered they are chronologically stored? because at one point i tried cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5